# package ‘slidify’ not available as a binary package for R version 3.1.3

Tags: r

This what happen when i try to install slidify package

install.packages("slidify")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/user pc/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘slidify’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)

Comment: It doesn't exist on CRAN; only [GitHub](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify).  Use `library(devtools); install_github('ramnathv/slidify', ref = 'dev'); install_github('ramnathv/slidifyLibraries', ref = 'dev')`

Answer (score 3):

The following steps worked for me

1. Use this commands Check if you have '**devtools**' installed or not :

   ```
   is.installed <- function(mypkg) is.element(mypkg, installed.packages()[,1])
   is.installed('devtools')
   ```

   if it prints '**true**' go to step **2** else you have to install **devtools**
   , use the following to install it

   ```
   install.packages("devtools")
   ```

   after successfully installation go to step **2**
2. Install '**slidify**' from github with the following commands

   ```
   library(devtools);
   install_github('ramnathv/slidify', ref = 'dev');
   ```
3. To check if is was installed successfully, use

   ```
   is.installed('slidify')
   ```